# Adding scopes to OAuth 1.0 authorization request with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

How do I add **scopes** to my authRequest?

```
public void PrepareAuthorizationRequest(Uri authCallbakUrl)
{
    var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);

    // request access
    consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authCallbakUrl, null, null));

    throw new NoRedirectToAuthPageException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope isn't a defined concept in OAuth 1.0, which you're using in this sample.  To define the scope of requested access, you should read the documentation of the service provider you're using and include the required additional parameters.  Assuming the service provider wants you to include a `scope` parameter, you should pass it in with the second parameter, like so:

```
var requestParameters = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "scope", "http://some/scope" },
};
consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authCallbackUrl, requestParameters, null));
```