# Want to request authorization to gmail with dotnetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I use dotnetOpenAuth. I want to request authorization to the user's gamil.

Do I need to use openId first?

Cannot find a decent tutorail. Can anyone help?

Tried this code unsuccesfully. Anyway I don't seems to ask for Gmail scope at the auth request, so I'm confused

```
public void PrepareAuthorizationRequest(Uri authCallbakUrl)
{
    var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);

    // request access
    consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authCallbakUrl, null, null));

    throw new NoRedirectToAuthPageException();
}

public ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse ProcessAuthorizationRequest()
{
    ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse response;
    // Process result from the service provider
    var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);
    var accessTokenResponse = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();

    // If we didn't have an access token response, this wasn't called by the service provider
    if (accessTokenResponse == null)
        response = new ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse
                       {
                           IsAuthorized = false
                       };
    else
    {
        // Extract the access token
       string accessToken = accessTokenResponse.AccessToken;
       response = new ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse
        {
            IsAuthorized = true,
            Token = accessToken,
            Secret = mConsumerTokenManager.GetTokenSecret(accessToken)
        };
    }
    return response;
}

private string Test2()
{
    // Process result from linked in
    var google = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);
  //  var accessToken = GetAccessTokenForUser();
    var accessToken = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the user's profile information
    var endpoint = GoogleConsumerConsts.GetGmailFeedsEndpoint;// new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
    var request = google.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(endpoint, accessToken);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    return (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to use OpenID if you just want to access the user's Gmail.  OpenID is for when you want to authenticate the user.  OAuth is for when you want to access the user's data.

You need to include the scope parameter in your authorization request as described in this question: [Adding scopes to OAuth 1.0 authorization request with DotNetOpenAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546780/adding-scopes-to-oauth-1-0-authorization-request-with-dotnetopenauth/9551676#9551676).

Comment: If i don't use openAuth, what should I save in the DB do identify the user for next time? is requestToken permanent and unique? What is the flow for second time user?

Comment: No a request token or access token isn't persistent.  If you want to be able to identify the user for next time, then OpenID *is* appropriate to use (in addition to OAuth to actually read their gmail).  In this case you should check out the `openidrelyingpartywebforms/loginplusoauth.aspx` sample, which demos logging a user in with Google *and* getting access to their gmail address book.

Comment: Will it cause to user double redirect? once for authentication and one for authorization?

Comment: @AndrewArnott So whoever uses authorization only is doing so for one login only? and what is the TokenManager for if all is temporary?

Comment: @user1065869 No double-redirect will be necessary, if done using the OpenID+OAuth extension as the `loginplusoauth.aspx` sample I pointed to demonstrates.  The user will see Google once, to authenticate and authorize at the same time.

Comment: @EladBenda Authorization can outlast a single login -- the access token should be stored with the consumer app's database record for that user's account so that the next time the user logs in (with OpenID) you'll already have an access token you can use.  It also would let you use the access token even if the user isn't currently logged in (to do offline work).  The TokenManager stores tokens and their secrets so that you can use access tokens and have their secrets supplied as necessary.

Comment: @AndrewArnott I'm confused: you say "No a request token or access token isn't persistent" but then you suggest: "The access token should be stored with the consumer app's database record". Can you please explain? In the DB what should I relate the access token to? as I never take credentials nor userId  from the user, only google does. Or am I missing some flow?

Comment: @EladBenda, if you've authenticated the user yourself on your site, or used OpenID to do so, then you have a user record in your database, and that's where you should store the access token.  Every time you ask for authorization from Google you get a *new* access_token, so that's why I say it's not persistent, but your app can certainly persist it and use it offline for as long as Google doesn't revoke or expire it.

Comment: @EladBenda If on the other hand you don't store user records in your database, didn't authenticate using OpenID and just want to read the user's Google data temporarily, you can discard the access token when you're done using it.